# Is there any problem to partition my notebook's harddisk after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 on my notebook. I had selected three partitions for Ubuntu root (/), Swap and EFI. Other seven partitions were selected as "*`do not use this partition`*". After installing Ubuntu, I need to change the size of those seven partitions. I deleted them and created seven new partitions with disks (GNOME Disks). Will it make any affect on my Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't affect your ubuntu installation.